# error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'main()::turma*' in assignment

Tags: c

Estou tentando compilar o meu código e apresenta o erro informado acima

> error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'main()::turma*' in assignment"

na linha 21 `(ptr_turma =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);)`

Segue o código:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

   struct turma {
        float matricula;
        char nome_aluno[30];
        float nota1;
        float nota2;
        float nota3;

    };
    int  i;
    char nome_turma[30];


    struct turma Turma, *ptr_turma;
    ptr_turma = &Turma;
    ptr_turma =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);

    printf (">> Calculo de notas <<");
    printf ("\n\n Informe o nome da turma: ");
    gets (nome_turma);
    printf ("\n\n\Informe os dados solicitados dos alunos (digite -1 na matricula para sair)...");

    while(prt_turma[i].matricula == -1){
        printf("\nMatricula: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr_turma[i].matricula);
            if(ptr_turma[i].matricula == -1){
                    break;
            }
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nNome: ");
        gets(ptr_turma[i].nome_aluno);
        printf("\n\Nota 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr_turma[i].nota1);
        printf("\nNota 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr_turma[i].nota2);
        printf("\nNota 3: ");
        scanf("%d", &ptr_turma[i].nota3);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

O seu código tem vários erros. O meu conselho, e que eu considero mais importante é tomar extrema atenção aos avisos e erros que o compilador dá. Mesmo os avisos são na maior parte (senão quase todos mesmo) erros.

Vamos então passar por todos eles, um por um:

- `ptr_turma =(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*100);`

  > main.c|21|warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

  Se pretende criar um array de `turma` então não pode ser `sizeof(int)` e sim `sizeof(struct turma)` e o *cast* para `(struct turma*)`, assim:

  ```
  ptr_turma = (struct turma*)malloc(sizeof(struct turma)*100);
  ```

  Se quiser simplificar faça antes:

  ```
  ptr_turma = malloc(sizeof(struct turma)*100);
  ```

  Que a conversão é implicita.
- `while(prt_turma[i].matricula == -1){`

  > main.c|28|error: ‘prt_turma’ undeclared (first use in this function)|

  Aqui `prt_turma` ficou mesmo mal escrito, e deveria seria `ptr_turma`.
- `printf ("\n\n\Informe os dados solicitados dos alunos (digite -1 na matricula para sair)...");`

  > main.c|26|warning: unknown escape sequence: '\I'|

  Tem uma `\` a mais. Devia ser `\n\nInforme` ao invés de `\n\n\Informe`.
- `scanf("%d", &ptr_turma[i].matricula);`

  > main.c|30|warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]

  O tipo do campo `matricula` na estrutura é `float`, logo a leitura tem de ser com `%f` e não `%d`. O mesmo se aplica a todos os outros campos que estão a ser lidos do mesmo tipo. Aconselho no entanto a ponderar se `matricula` era suposto ser mesmo um `float` ? Pois isso parece no mínimo estranho.

  > main.c|30|warning: ‘i’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

  Para além do aviso do tipo, também a variável `i` não foi inicializada. Uma vez que se trata de um array o normal seria inicializar com `0` lá no topo:

  ```
  int  i = 0;  //<-----
  char nome_turma[30];
  ```

  Agora falta ver o que pretende fazer com esse `i`, uma vez que também não vejo nenhum incremento no laço/ciclo. Isso significa que o seu laço nunca sai do mesmo elemento, pois o `i` nunca volta a ser atribuido.
- `printf("\n\Nota 1: ");`

  > main.c|37|warning: unknown escape sequence: '\N'|

  Outra `\` que ficou a mais neste, e deveria ser:

  ```
  printf("\nNota 1: ");
  ```

E com isto tudo deve ficar sem avisos e erros! (talvez?)

> Porquê talvez ?

Porque se calhar a compilar o código com um compilador de c++11 irá na verdade ver dois avisos:

> main.c|24|warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
>
> main.c|24|warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.|

Acontece que a função `gets` é tão perigosa e má, que foi de facto removida no C++11, e como o próprio aviso indica, não deve ser utilizada.

Uma alternativa boa em C (e não C++) é o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), ou até mesmo o [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) se manuseado corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Colega, copiando e colando seu código, verifiquei que existe problema na linha 28, onde é uma questão de corrigir a grafia.

```
  typedef struct turma {
    float matricula;
    char nome_aluno[30];
    float nota1;
    float nota2;
    float nota3;

} Turma;
```

fiz este ajuste.  E mais este:

```
 Turma *ptr_turma;

while(ptr_turma[i].matricula== -1){
```

A correção que citei logo no inicio.

Exite alguns ajustes para funcionar da forma que deseja.  Mais desta forma está rodando.  Espero ter ajudado.